# Is it possible to style generic Preference just like DialogPreference?

Tags: android, android-preferences, android-theme

I have a generic Preference which has an intent assigned, so when this preference is clicked, another Activity is opened.

What I want is to put that little arrow indicator ([this one](http://gliffer.ru/upload/content/d2c9a7a6017800edace793e3e3388cb5.png)), i.e. I want to style this Preference just like DialogPreference is styled.

I searched through Android's sources and found several related things, like *com.android.internal.R.attr.dialogPreferenceStyle* - which is passed to Preference constructor by DialogPreference, but it is internal. Also there's style named *"Preference.DialogPreference"* in android's *styles.xml*, but it's not public either.

Any hints? Obviously I can not use DialogPreference, because I'm not showing dialog, I'm showing an Activity, therefore custom Preference is needed....